# Sequelize findByPk returns null

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to find a user by his/her id. I used sequelize findByPk() and the response came back as null whereas I got all the data using findAll(). So the connection to the database is there.

controllers.js

```
module.exports = {
    findAll: function(req, res) {
        User.findAll()
        .then(user => {
            res.json(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => res.status(422).json(err));
    },
    findByPk: function(req, res) {
        User.findByPk(req.params.id)
        .then(user => {
            res.json(user)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
};
```

routes.js

```
router.get('/all', userController.findAll);
router.get('/oneUser', userController.findByPk);
```

Comment: you are using which version of sequelize ?

Comment: In sequelize v5, findById() was replaced by findByPk().

Comment: using Sequelize v5.19.

Comment: even through postman I am getting null.

Comment: In the end I used findAll() and looped through the results to get the user id. Not ideal as the web app will suffer when I have lots of data. Hopefully by that time though, sequelize would have found an answer to the problem. I haven't seen any solutions out there yet.

Comment: router.get(/oneUser/:id, userController.findByPk);  :id is missing in your for get req.params.id.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. How I have it now, as per the response below, does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that `req.params.id` contains a valid PK?  Does findByPk work if you test with a hard-coded value, e.g. `User.findByPk(1).then....` ?

If nothing else, you could use a where clause so you need not iterate:

```
findByPk: function(req, res) {
   User.findAll({where : {id : req.params.id }})  /* assumes pk is 'id' field */
   .then(user => {
      res.json(user)
   })
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested (thanks for the suggestion) and got this in the console:

```
Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value
```
And when I tried through postman, instead of returning null, it returned the static page which is what I set it to if the API wasn't being hit.

With hardcoding a value, I get null which per Sequelize documents means there's no value. But there is a value in the database!

Comment: So I hardcoded a value again using findOne({where: {id: 11}}) and it's returning the right input. I then tried passing the value from req.params.id and it's not returning anything.

Comment: Okay it was resolved by just accessing it like this: findOne({where: req.params.id}). I'm going to mark your answer as right because you helped me break down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and spend hours to resolve the issue.

Using `findByPk` is the best practice if we are searching one item from primary key. `findOne` or others are not good fit for this case

I finally fixed by adding `id` field into the model with `primaryKey` attribute.

```
id: {
  allowNull: false,
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
}
```

By default, `id` field is added to the model, but if the model has more than one field that is primary keyed, then we have to manually add `id` field as above.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I try my request on postman but then I console.log the id that I tried to have and it works so my request was good but I forgot a setting on postman test with adding id and number id here :

[Postman setting FindById](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNAr4.png)